# Installing a self-signed certificate in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, ssl, self-signed

The question:
I have an application running under tomcat which calls another application under the same tomcat via a gateways which has a self signed SSL certificate installed. When you call the link from your browser it warns you about potentially dangerous site, but you have an option to proceed anyway. However the tomcat cannot proceed anyway until it trusts the certificate.
The certificate is issued by KEMP technologies.
So how do I make tomcat to trust the certificate?
I have `.cer` and `.key` files.

OS: Windows 2008R2

Tomcat 7

Comment: As you have stated that "The certificate is issued by KEMP technologies." Tell us your certificate is self-signed or CA signed??

Comment: I am not sure how to answer that. It is issued by KEMP technologies however apparently it is not a trusted certificate for the browsers. When you buy a software load balancer from KEMP they provide you with that certificate.

Comment: Regardless of whether it is self-signed or Kemp-signed, you have to import it as a CA certificate into the *truststore* that will be used by Tomcat.